# Error in creating the connection. java.sql.sqlException

Tags: java

i am trying to create a database connection , but database is not in my localhost, so i provided the IP instead of localhost in

```
 Connection con= DriverManager.getConnection(conStr,user,pass);
```

where

```
constr="jdbc:mysql://10.0.0.1/Sigma"
```

but its giving

```
java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'15.3.0.4' (using password: NO)
```

but i login with the same user name and password

Comment: Can you login as `root` from the host `15.3.0.4` using no password?

Comment: Normally root is only GRANTed rights for 127.0.0.1.

Comment: 10.0.0.1 is a non routable IP address and in the response you have 15.3.0.4.
Double check you IP addresses.

Answer (score 0):

That's probably because the machine where you're running that code is has not that `15.3.0.4` IP, although you can connect from your machine which potentially has that IP.

You can try to create a `'root'@'%'` user who will be granted to access regardless where you are connecting from.